# Change the list size of bxslider with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have remove some item from the list of the BxSlider carousel.

But when I browse the carousel, BxSlider seems to still have the same count of item in the list (one slide is empty).

How can I fixed it ? There is a item count saved somewhere ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing slides you can call the `.reloadShow` method on the slider instance, and it will reload the show. Like

```
var slider =  $('#slider').bxSlider( { ... } );

// remove item

slider.reloadShow();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/H2NUu/